# get the answer of at command in android app

Tags: android, shell, at-command, su

first of all my mobile is rooted. and I'm sure because I tried several ways to know that. One of those ways is Root Checker Basic app.

I put this code in an app and tried and every thing is ok:

```
Process p;   
try {   
   // Preform su to get root privledges  
   p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");   

   // Attempt to write a file to a root-only   
   DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());   
   os.writeBytes("echo \"Do I have root?\" >/storage/extSdCard/temp.txt\n");  

   // Close the terminal  
   os.writeBytes("exit\n");   
   os.flush();   
   try {   
      p.waitFor();   
           if (p.exitValue() != 255) {   
              // TODO Code to run on success  
              toastMessage("root");  
           }   
           else {   
               // TODO Code to run on unsuccessful  
               toastMessage("not root");      
           }   
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {   
      // TODO Code to run in interrupted exception  
       toastMessage("not root");   
   }   
} catch (IOException e) {   
   // TODO Code to run in input/output exception  
    toastMessage("not root");   
}
```

toastMessage is just a function to get the answer "root".
but when I made some changes in this code to read the answer of an at command the app stopped and didn't get any response.

```
    Process p;   
    try {   
       // Preform su to get root privledges  
       p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");   

       // Attempt to write a file to a root-only   
       DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());   
       os.writeBytes("echo \"AT+CQI?\"\n");  

       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
               new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
       int read;
       char[] buffer = new char[4096];
       StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
       while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
           output.append(buffer, 0, read);
       }
       reader.close();
       try {
        p.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
       tv.setText(output.toString());


       // Close the terminal  
       os.writeBytes("exit\n");   
       os.flush();   

    } catch (IOException e) {   
       // TODO Code to run in input/output exception  
        tv.setText("not root");   
    }
```

tv is a Text View

what is the mistake I've done
I tried a lot of ways to read the answer of that at command but the problem always in the read.

Comment: Try adding some breakpoints to see where it gets stuck.

Comment: because I implement this app on my mobile I don't know how to add break point unless it will run on the emulator... I tried to drop some of code like while and wait when I drop the both the app run but of course don't get the answer.

Comment: it dose not work on the emulator like on the mobile. the answer in the emulator is not rooted. while in the mobile (no response at all).
thats why I cant add break point

Comment: You can set breakpoints on your phone the same way as in the emulator